# Ruby MRI 1.8.7: Spawn process directly in code?

Tags: ruby, fork

I understand that there are various ways to spawn new processes in Ruby (e.g. backticks, system(), exec(), etc...)

However, is it possible to spawn a new process directly with code passed as a block?
Just like forks (fork {... block ...}).

My problem is that I don't want to use forks as I don't want to copy all the memory (problematic in my case because of writing), I want to spawn a "fresh" project without calling an external ruby file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fork` is the only way to do this. However, on Linux at least, and I think on OSX too, `fork` is implemented as *copy on write*, meaning that until an area of memory is written to in the child process, it points directly to the area of the old parent process. So, no problem.

**Edit**: Nevermind. The above is wrong. Here's what I would do:

```
code = "puts 'hi'"
result = nil
popen("ruby") do |pipe|
  pipe.puts code
  pipe.close_write
  result = pipe.read
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in Ruby 1.8.7 all the memory will have to be copied the first time the garbage collector runs due to the mark and sweep algorithm used.  For more info, see http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/3/23/why-you-should-be-excited-about-garbage-collection-in-ruby-2-0

Comment: @wally: oh! Didn't see 1.8 in the title.